# Is $0$ a cluster point of the set $\{0\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I just read the theorem

> A subset of R is closed if and only if it contains all of its cluster points.

And I found that the set {0} is closed (Is that correct?), then the set {0} should contains all its cluster points, right? But I just checked the definition of cluster point in the textbook (it appears at the beginning of the limit of function) and found that 0 is not the cluster point of the set {0}

I want to know where the false is ?

Comment: Do you think that the set is not closed? If yes then can you give a cluster point which is not in the set?      The definition says that A set is closed iff it contains all its cluster point. If 0 is not the cluster point then why do you even worry about it?

Comment: I got it ! I just thought 0 "should" be a cluster point of the set .Then the set does not have a cluster point, right? Thank you. But wait a minute, the set {0} contains the element 0 !

Comment: Post the definition of "cluster point" in your book.

Comment: I think it appears at the answer provided by Anthony Ter .

Comment: @YangGao The set {0}  contains the element 0! Yes, It contains. So what?

Comment: @YangGao Why 0 should be a cluster point and why do you feel like that?

Answer (score 2):

If $0$ was a cluster point of $\{0\}$ then for every $\delta > 0$ there would exist an $x \neq 0, x \in N_\delta(0)$ such that $x \in \{0\}$. clearly no such $x$ exists, for any $\delta$. Thus $0$ is not a cluster point of $\{0\}$.

So is $\{0 \}$ closed? Does it contain all of its limit points? Well, $\emptyset \subseteq \{0\}$, so $\{0\}$ is closed.

Comment: Thanks. Now I really get it . The closed set contains all of its cluster point but not all of its elements! Thank you!

Comment: Now the empty set is the only cluster point of the set, right? Just a little "weird".

Comment: No,the empty set isn't a point. The empty set represents the set of limit points, and I was trying to show that that set is contained in $\{0\}$. I should have used $\subseteq$, not $\in$. I'll edit it now.

Comment: So the set does not have a cluster point ? wow

Comment: Yep, in fact, no finite subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has a cluster point.

Comment: The finite subsets of R are closed, but they don't have any cluster point. So should the theorem I mentioned in the question have a premise that the set have at least cluster point? Thank you very much!!

Comment: You can do that, but it would be redundant. The set is closed iff it contains all its limit points, so if there are no limit points to begin with, the set will be closed.

Comment: I got it.Thank you!